# How to display WordPress Posts in a CakePHP Template/**/*.ctp file?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

Is it even possible? If so, do I need to download a plugin to make it work?

(The Wordpress directory is located in webroot/blog/)

I don't want to customize my entire wordpress blog to look like my website when I could just (if possible) display all blog posts on a .ctp file.

Comment: I don't know anything about cakephp but it sounds like you're looking for the WordPress rest api https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly with the WordPress API! Thanks.